# OCR API for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, ocr

Is there any 3rd Party OCR library compatible with windows phone 8 or 7

I have used Hawaii Project its not working ,, properly ,, is there any other library which I can use ., ??

..... I have Used OCR - IT and i dont know why .. result is giving me webException .. which means there is nothing in response or ,, the requested uri is not valid ..... can any1 help .................

public void SendToOCRIt()
        {
            string imageUrl = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // i cant disclose the location of the image

```
        XElement xe = new XElement("Job",new XElement("InputURL", imageUrl));

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();

        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "text/xml";

        wc.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("https://svc.webservius.com/v1/wisetrend/wiseocr/submit?wsvKey=OZSpgQ6RF7C8xYYYYTpif6E2XXXXXXXXXX", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),"POST", "<Job><InputURL>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</InputURL></Job>");

        wc.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Error != null)
                {
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());
                        });
                }

                else
                {
                    ResponseText.Text = e.Result.ToString();
                }

            });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check Microsoft's OCR library. It works for WP8.
It is available through NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Ocr/.

Comment: Has anyone used this `Microsoft.Windows.Ocr` OCR Library to do ServerSide OCR stuff using ASP.Net etc? I am working on a project that needs OCR functionality, and it would be great to know if anyone else has had success doing this serverside.

Answer (score 0):

you can also check devscope ocr for win8rt & windows phone (.net version also available).
includes an *amazing* sample Windows Phone 8 Demo App with full source code. :)

Not free, but I think it's a very valid option if you compare to all others, 100% native wp8, *no cloud*. royalty free

(disclaimer: I work at DevScope, although not in the OCR SDK team , but trust me, those guys know about OCR & windows phone :) )

Regards,

Rui